# RegExp: Ignore 2 consecutive slashes but match 1 single slash

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm creating a string validator using RegExp and I need it to match single slash (`/`) but not match double slashes (`//` OR `https?://`). I need exactly the opposite of what `(\/{2,2})` does.

The final RegExp I need will be consisted from this sub expression and `[^A-Za-zÀ-ü0-9\.:_ @ü+-]`

Thanks for help!

Comment: [`(?<!\/)\/(?!\/)`](https://regex101.com/r/CYG8xA/1)

Comment: Thanks for answering, but the issue with the negative lookbehind is the browser compatibility: https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind

Is there any other solution?

Comment: You can use [`(?:^|[^\/])(\/)(?!\/)`](https://regex101.com/r/sQ4AXv/1) and then reference the first capturing group. It also depends on what exactly you want to do (i.e. how do you need to combine it with the other regex).

Comment: Thanks for help! This is what I need now I only need to combine it with the other negated set. I want the following:
`[^A-Za-zÀ-ü0-9\.:_ @ü+-]` AND `(?:^|[^\/])(\/)(?!\/)`, but there is no AND available in regex.

I need the regex to match the letters that are not in the first expression and the single or triple+ consecutive slashes (to skip only //).

How can they be combined to get this result?

Comment: Please provide some example of expected matched (and not matched) strings, *possibly editing the question*. See also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Is it possible to make this ( (?:^|[^\/])(\/)(?!\/) ) also catch 3 or more consecutive slashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match also the three slashes you can use this:

```
(?:^|[^\/])(\/(?:(?!\/)|\/{2,}))
```

For the rest, ou are right, there is no AND in regular expressions, but there is OR :-) For joining the two regexps you can use this:

```
^(?:[^A-Za-zÀ-ü0-9.:_ @ü+\-\/]|\/(?:(?!\/)|\/{2,}))*$
```

Notice that I added a `\/` in the first member of the alternation. So you remove from the valid characters also the slash, but you re-add it using alternation ensuring at the same time that it is not followed by a second slash OR it is followed by at least two slashes.

See a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/cLNE8Y/1).

Comment: The modification to catch 3 or more slashes works perfectly.

I found a workaround to make them work togheter:

`regex1.test(dataField) || regex2.test(dataField`

If any of these 2 return true, then there is a forbidden character and throws errors.

Thanks a lot for your professional and fast assistance!